# how to count duration of actions until last action happens (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm making battleship game and want to save gameplay duration in server.

I've tried some code but it is just timer and won't stop.

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 10);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("startTimeCounter").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code that does anything on the server. All you're doing is setting markup in the dom every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.